# SCORM success_status can't be failed due to German laws

Tags: scorm, scorm2004

We have SCORM classes that were published with Articulate that, due to German labor laws, the learner can't fail.  How can you tweak, say, SCORM2004Function.js so that the value of cmi.success_status is either "passed" or, if is supposed to be "failed," is instead "unknown?"

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please allow me to point out, that there is a data model element `cmi.credit` (`cmi.core.credit` in SCORM 1.2) that is set by the LMS and read only for the SCO, that indicates whether or not the learner can take credit for the SCO.

However, this might not be acceptable/sufficient for your purposes; if you really want to hack the JavaScript API included in the SCORM package, you probably simply have to insert a line within the `SetValue()` function (or its similarly named wrapper function) similar to the following

```
    # pseudo code
    if (element == "cmi.success_status" && value == "failed") {
        value = "unknown"
    }
```

That should basically do the trick, as the `SetValue()` API function (`LMSSetValue` in SCORM 1.2) is the only place where data model element values can be set.